# deleting association @ManyToMany is not always working in Spring Data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring data,
i'm trying to deal with associating (@ManyToMany) users with roles that are from an enum (Edit : I removed the enum that was adding complexity for no use).
I have no problem to add roles to a user, but to delete it's much more a problem.

I read a lot about the best ways to map @manytomany associations.

My User Class :

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable (name = "user_roles",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public void addRole(Role role){
        this.roles.add(role);
        role.getUsers().add(this);
    }

    public void removeRole(Role role){
        this.roles.remove(role);
        role.getUsers().remove(this);
    }
}
```

My Role Class :

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String designation;

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    public Role(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }
}
```

And my test :

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LibraryApiWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        Role user = new Role(RoleDesignation.USER);
        Role admin = new Role(RoleDesignation.ADMIN);

        roleRepository.save(user);
        roleRepository.save(admin);

        User user1 = new User("****@hotmail.fr", encoder.encode("1234"), "***", "***", user);
        User user2 = new User("*****@gmail.com", encoder.encode("1234"),"****", "*****user);

        user1.addRole(admin);

        userRepository.save(user1);
        userRepository.save(user2);

        user1.removeRole(admin);
        userRepository.save(user1);

        user2.addRole(admin);
        userRepository.save(user2);

        user2.removeRole(admin);
        userRepository.save(user2);
    }
}
```

This one works (Edit : after cleaning up associations, it doesn't work anymore):

```
        user1.removeRole(admin);
        userRepository.save(user1);
```

hibernate perform a delete

but the second one doesn't :

```
        user2.removeRole(admin);
        userRepository.save(user2);
```

hibernate just does select and no delete.
I try to found in the log if it was an "un-scheduling entity deletion", but i couldn't find it (i never managed to properly deal this problem by the way).

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Try to log your JPA statements. Then, you would know a little bit better what's happening. Try to use the debugger to see when which queries are executed. (Of course, you could then update your post with the details.)

Comment: I'm actually having these parameters in application.properties ```spring.jpa.show-sql=true, logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG,
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE```and there is nothing i can see telling me what's going on. I just see some select request beeing performed and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very good approach to keep the relationships synchronised (code and database) with add and remove methods. However, this means that you need proper methods for `hashCode` and `equals`. In [his article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/), Vlad Mihalcea described quite good what the best and easiest way is.

In your case, you would have to add the following code.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
    User that = (User) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.getId(), that.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 56;
}
```

You would then have to change the classes for `Role`.

Comment: thanjks for your answer, i read a lot about these articles, and i have to admitt that i don't get much about this. I tried the code you wrote, but it's the same. One question, why hashCode return 56 ?